# create a numpy array with a variable

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an variable `i_k` from `I[0]`

```
i_k = I[0]
```

where

```
I:

[[0.2]
 [0.3]
 [0.4]
 [0.5]
 [0.6]]
```

So `i_k` should be 0.2.

Then when I am trying to create a numpy array

```
H_k = np.array([[i_k,1]])
```

instead having `[[0.2  1.]]`, what I have is

```
[[array([0.2]) 1]]
```

I am confused. How do I get `[[0.2  1.]]`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`I` is a 2D array, so when you say `i_k = I[0]` you get `[0.2]`.  You can fix this by saying `i_k = I[0][0]` or `i_k = I.flat[0]`.